# Files corrupt when downloaded through php header

Tags: php

I have a download link on my website from where we can download attachments. The pdf file is downloading perfectly but the images, docs and zip file are downloading as corrupt.

Below is the code which I am using for download. The code is working fine in my local pc but not on the server.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($FilePath));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($FilePath));
readfile($FilePath);
exit;
```

Comment: have you tried with different content types? While a PDF can be understood as an application/octet-stream, an image, a document and an archive might be not.

Comment: but the same code is working in my local pc for all file extensions.

Comment: humor me, try another content type

Answer (score 0):

The corruption occurs if your php script echoes anything before your headers.

Try using the same code, but in a separate php script.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```